# How to set a div's content to another div's content

Tags: javascript, html

So I have two divs

```
<div id="1"><p>Hello<p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Goodbye<p></div>
```

And I am wondering if there is a simple technique to set div "1" equal to div "2" ?

So, the end result will be:

```
<div id="1"><p>Goodbye<p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Goodbye<p></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you need is to show some effort and/or research. Have you at least tried anything? We're not here to code for you. We are here to help you with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Do exactly that..

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("1");
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = div1.innerHTML;
```

Comment: More specifically, if I wanted to set the first div's paragraph to the second's, how would I do that? (i.e. `var div1 = document.getElementById("1 p");
document.getElementById("2 p").innerHTML = div1.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 2):

Try it using javascript

```
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("2").innerHTML
```

to get specific tags within an element use:

```
var x = document.getElementById("1");
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

or in one line:

```
document.getElementById("1").getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML;
```